# Which method is more efficient to replace pixel values in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to replace pixel values in the area of image that meet certain conditions with other values.

For example, the pixel value meeting the condition 'A' is replaced with 1, and the pixel value meeting the condition 'B' is replaced with 2.

I can do that by 2 ways in GEE Python API:

(1) combine updateMask() and blend()

```
A = data_a.eq(a)
B = data_b.eq(b)
one = ee.Image.constant(1)
two = ee.Image.constant(2)
result = one.updateMask(A).blend(two.updateMask(B))
```

(2) use image.expression()

```
result = ee.Image().expression(
     '(data_a == a) ? 1 :' + \
      '(data_b == b) ? 2 : 0', 
     {
        'data_a' : data_a,
        'data_b' : data_b
     }
)
```

I did some testing by exporting the result to Google Drive, but sometimes (1) was faster and sometimes (2) was faster. Since I'm working with large scale and long time series data, I need to consider which method is theoretically more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test performance of Earth Engine code, I suggest using the [profiler](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/computation_overview#profiler) to compare Earth Engine Compute Units ([EECUs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/computation_overview#eecus)). That will remove a lot of the variables like network latency, storage ingress/egress, and server load that might affect Drive export times.

You can theoretically do profiling in the Python API, but I was getting some suspicious results when I tried to compare your methods using `computePixels`, so I ended up porting them into the Code Editor with a slight modification to make it easier to test with random data. The test code and results are below.

### Blend Method

```js
function blend_method(data_a, data_b) {
  var A = data_a.lt(0.5)
  var B = data_b.gt(0.5)
  var one = ee.Image.constant(1)
  var two = ee.Image.constant(2)
  return one.updateMask(A).blend(two.updateMask(B))
}

var result = blend_method(ee.Image.random(), ee.Image.random());
Map.addLayer(result);
```

Averaged over 5 runs, the `blend_method` took **2.44 ± 0.22** EECU-seconds. Here's one example result from the profiler:

[image: Profile results for the blend method]

### Expression Method

```js
function expression_method(data_a, data_b) {
  return ee.Image().expression(
      '(data_a < 0.5) ? 1 : (data_b > 0.5) ? 2 : 0',
      {
          'data_a': data_a,
          'data_b': data_b,
      }
  )
}

var result = expression_method(ee.Image.random(), ee.Image.random());
Map.addLayer(result)
```

Averaged over 5 runs, the `expression_method` took **1.58 ± 0.04** EECU-seconds. Here's an example from the profiler:

[image: Profile results for the expression method]

### Results

This isn't a perfect test, but it suggests that the `expression` method is more efficient in this scenario. It's worth noting that `ee.Image.expression` is a convenience method that gets parsed into other methods by the server. If you look at the calls in the profiler, the expression gets parsed into `lt`, `gt`, and `where` methods. If you're looking for maximum efficiency, you could avoid the expression parsing by using `ee.Image.where` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function just for this type of operation: [`ee.Image.remap()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-remap).

```py
result = data.remap(
  [a, b],
  to = [1, 2],
  defaultValue = 0,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in my case, the replacement conditions and values may depend on different images, in which case the `ee.Image.remap()` function may no longer be appropriate. Sorry for the ambiguity in my question, it has been modified now.